# Deriving PDE to evolve a planar curve to a circle, while preserving its length.

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

I would like to ask, how could I derive a PDE that evolves a planar curve to a circle while preserving its length ? (The problem states that there is no need to show that the steady state is a circle, but there is a need to prove that the length is preserved). I'm rather new to this field and when presented with this problem, I really have no idea how to begin.

Comment: http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.jdg/1214439902

Comment: Thanks! Will take a detailed reading of this article to see how the information inside will help!